# How do I change the direction in which the width constraint changes for UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton

I have the following UIButtons and I'm trying to get the red "Start" button to elongate and cover the blue button  when tapped:

[image: Buttons]

I plan to have the Start button elongate and then hide the Save button. However, when I try to do this, the start button elongates towards the right.

I have the buttons set up with constraints in IB so I'm changing the constraint in the animation block:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {

           self.toggleButtonWidth.constant *= 2 //toggleButtonWidth is the width constraint of the red button

           self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        })
```

However, this causes the red button to elongate to the right and off screen:

[image: problem]

I want to elongate to the left.

PS: I know the buttons and their layout doesn't look pretty, I'm still trying to figure out functionality before doing design

Comment: Means you need to overlap red button on blue button when you will tap on that. I'm right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pin the start button on the right (trailing space to container). With the right edged pinned, the only place the button can "grow" is to the left.

Another thing you can try is getting rid of the width constraint, pinning the left side of the start button (leading space) to the **container** (i.e. NOT to the save button), and then reducing the constant of that constraint in the animations closure. Something like

```
leadingConstraint.constant = leadingConstraint.constant - saveButton.bounds.size.width
```

It's a little hard to decide what the best route is without knowing how you've laid out your auto layout constraints.

Whatever you do, you will probably need to reduce the alpha of the save button. Otherwise the save button may still be visible when the start button "covers" it. You could also do this in the animations closure by adding a statement like `saveButton.alpha = 0` Lowering its alpha just makes it invisible, however, so you may need to hide it completely (`button.hidden = true`) so that the user can't accidentally still tap it.

Comment: Your first suggestion worked. Thanks! Also, I should have displayed all my constraints, sorry about that.